# How to do something when radio button is going from checked to unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function in Javascript that changes an attribute on a radio button (This is so that I can detect what radio button is checked) when someone clicks off/on it. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loweman/q8hwh15s/) explaining a little more of what I am looking to do. The only problem with the code in the jsFiddle is that it is in jQuery and I do not understand enough jQuery to convert it back to its pure Javascript counterpart. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Loweman/4wc4q5bw/) is my attempt to convert jQuery to Javascript. I could totally just copy the code and just use it but then I would not be learning anything.

I have been trying to figure this out for the last 4 ish hours and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Alex

```js
InitRadio('name');

function InitRadio(name) {
  val = 0;
  $.each($(':radio[name="' + name + '"]'), function() {
    $(this).val(val++);
    $(this).attr('chk', '0');
    $(this).on("click", function(event) {
      SetRadioButtonChkProperty($(this).val(), name);
      document.getElementById('1').innerText = document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('chk');
      document.getElementById('2').innerText = document.getElementById('input2').getAttribute('chk');
      document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('input3').getAttribute('chk');
    });
  });
  document.getElementById('1').innerText = document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('chk');
  document.getElementById('2').innerText = document.getElementById('input2').getAttribute('chk');
  document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('input3').getAttribute('chk');
}

function SetRadioButtonChkProperty(val, name) {
  $.each($(':radio[name="' + name + '"]'), function() {
    if ($(this).val() != val)
      $(this).attr('chk', '0');
    else {
      if ($(this).attr('chk') == '0')
        $(this).attr('chk', '1');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input1">
<p id="1"></p>
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input2">
<p id="2"></p>
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input3">
<p id="3"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you're partially through converting jQuery to javascript and you're having difficulty with the conversion due to lack of understanding about jQuery.

Below is [my conversion](http://jsfiddle.net/5m4a1xsu/) with jQuery lines commented out and followed by their most direct Javascript equivalent. Keep in mind that some jQuery functions have different conversions depending on how you use them (though none of your code has this issue). Also, this code could benefit from a lot of cleanup both due to the conversion and due to issues with your own code. I've avoided doing any cleanup in favor of demonstrating the jQuery/Javascript equivalency.

```js
InitRadio('name');

function InitRadio(name) {
  val = 0;
  //$.each($(':radio[name="' + name + '"]'), function() {
  var radioButtons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="'+name+'"]'));
  radioButtons.forEach(function(element,index){
    //$(this).val(val++);
    element.value = val++;
    //$(this).attr('chk', '0');
    element.setAttribute('chk','0');
    //$(this).on("click", function(event) {
    element.addEventListener('click',function(event){
      //SetRadioButtonChkProperty($(this).val(), name);
      SetRadioButtonChkProperty(element.value, name);
      document.getElementById('1').innerText = document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('chk');
      document.getElementById('2').innerText = document.getElementById('input2').getAttribute('chk');
      document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('input3').getAttribute('chk');
    });
  });
  document.getElementById('1').innerText = document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('chk');
  document.getElementById('2').innerText = document.getElementById('input2').getAttribute('chk');
  document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('input3').getAttribute('chk');
}

function SetRadioButtonChkProperty(val, name) {
  //$.each($(':radio[name="' + name + '"]'), function() {
  var radioButtons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="'+name+'"]'));
  radioButtons.forEach(function(element,index){
    //if ($(this).val() != val)
    if (element.value != val)
      //$(this).attr('chk', '0');
      element.setAttribute('chk','0');
    else {
      //if ($(this).attr('chk') == '0')
      if (element.getAttribute('chk') == '0')
        //$(this).attr('chk', '1');
        element.setAttribute('chk','1');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input1">
<p id="1"></p>
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input2">
<p id="2"></p>
<input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='name' id="input3">
<p id="3"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the conversion it is starting to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want.
You can try it out in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1fa59m4/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="RadioList"> 
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" value="r1" name="radio"> R1
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" value="r2" name="radio"> R2
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" value="r3" name="radio"> R3
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" value="r4" name="radio"> R4 
</div> 
<div class="statusRadio">
  <p>Checked Radio value: <b id="statusChecked">none</b></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(document).on('click', '.radioBtn', function() {
    var valRadio = this.value;
    $('#statusChecked').html(valRadio);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the radio button is checked, there's no need to set a custom attribute. Just look at its `checked` property.

Comment: Sorry for my wording. I was trying to say just change an element not necessarily weather it is checked or not.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Pretty much I want to do exactly what the jQuery code in the question does but  I just want to do it in pure Javascript.